# How to avoid similar function definitions in Python?

Tags: python, function

I have a bunch of very similar functions in my Python code, which look as follows:

```
def callback1(msg):
    m = MsgX(msg)
    a = msg_type_a()
    a.x = m.x
    pub2.publish(a)

def callback2(msg):
    m = MsgY(msg)
    b = msg_type_b()
    b.t = m.t
    b.u = m.u
    pub2.publish(b)

# ... and a couple more in the same fashion
```

Is there some way to avoid the repetition in defining these functions without influencing the execution speed?

Comment: Apart from the `pub2.publish(a)` there isn’t really anything identical in those functions. Plus, `a` is not even a variable in the function scope?

Comment: I'm assuming the second one is supposed to have `pub2.publish(b)`.

Comment: @poke: There's a pretty clear parallel structure. They have a different `MsgSpam` type, a different `msg_type_spam` type, and a different list of attributes, but otherwise they do the same thing.

Comment: @abarnert Of course I see the structure, but it’s hard to tell what exactly is variable about this kind of function (you did a good job in your answer though).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a macro for this; functions are first-class objects, and can be built dynamically:

```
def make_callback(m_type, other_type, *attrs):
    def callback(msg):
        m = m_type(msg)
        a = other_type()
        for attr in attrs:
            setattr(a, attr, getattr(m, attr))
        pub2.publish(a)
    return callback

callback1 = make_callback(MsgX, msg_type_a, 'x')
callback2 = make_callback(MsgY, msg_type_b, 't', 'u')
```

If you're willing to standardize the types in some way, you can make this even simpler. For example, if every one of those `other_type` things is a `namedtuple`-ish type (something that has `_fields_` or `__slots__` or some other iterable of attribute names):

```
def make_callback(m_type, other_type):
    def callback(msg):
        m = m_type(msg)
        a = other_type()
        for attr in other_type._fields_:
            setattr(a, attr, getattr(m, attr))
        pub2.publish(a)
    return callback

callback1 = make_callback(MsgX, msg_type_a)
callback2 = make_callback(MsgY, msg_type_b)
```

Or, if the `msg_type`s just know how to construct themselves from the `MsgTypes`:

```
def make_callback(m_type, other_type):
    def callback(msg):
        m = m_type(msg)
        a = other_type(m)
        pub2.publish(a)
    return callback

callback1 = make_callback(MsgX, msg_type_a)
callback2 = make_callback(MsgY, msg_type_b)
```

Or, if the `MsgTypes` know how to transform themselves into `msg_types` (possibly even dynamically-generated ones):

```
def make_callback(m_type):
    def callback(msg):
        m = m_type(msg)
        pub2.publish(m.to_other_type())
    return callback

callback1 = make_callback(MsgX, msg_type_a)
callback2 = make_callback(MsgY, msg_type_b)
```

And so on. All the basic OO designs are available in Python when they're appropriate (it's hard to know what's appropriate from your toy example), but you have lots of reflective/dynamic features to fall back to when they're not.

---

Will this affect performance?

Well, you are either looping over a list of 2 things or adding an extra function call, which takes a few nanoseconds. But is that really important? If so, you'd almost certainly want to change your design so that the `msg_type` types can be constructed more cheaply (e.g., in a single call), and so on, and while doing that, you can fit in something that makes this part easier to optimize as well.

Comment: I just tested the execution speed. For this specific case there was no noticable difference.

Comment: @DanielEckert: Good; testing is always better than guessing. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are no macros, but you can create a function that defines another function and returns it:

```
def make_callback(msg_type, msg_type_func, attrs_to_copy):
    def callback(msg):
        m = msg_type(msg)
        x = msg_type_func()
        for attr in attrs_to_copy:
            setattr(x, attr, getattr(m, attr))
        pub2.publish(x)
    return callback
```

Then you would do something like:

```
callback1 = make_callback(MsgX, msg_type_a, ['x'])
callback2 = make_callback(MsgY, msg_type_b, ['t', 'u'])
```

Depending on how complicated your logic is and what exactly may vary in the different functions, you may want to instead write a class that breaks the callback functionality down into parts (e.g., a "set attributes" step and a "publish step") and provides a single "go" method to execute them all.  Also, if you know what combinations are meaningful (i.e., you know that `MsgX` always goes with `msg_type_a`), then you can make that information explicit in a dictionary somewhere, and use that dictionary to derive various parts of the call from one or a few "key" values.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you are after classes, they allow you to assign methods and variables to an otherwise identically structured object